# I want to allow html tag when use the wp_trim_words

Tags: wordpress, trim

I want to show some content of post in anchor tag and show as link but I have use `wp_trim_words` function I don't know how to allow the html tags.

```
$more = ' <a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '" class="readMoreBtn">Read More</a>';
$content = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50, $more );
echo   do_shortcode($content);
```

Comment: But through the_content all content shows i want to show limited content.

Comment: I totally missed the stripping of the tags by `wp_trim_words()`. Updated the answer, and tested it, should be working now @pia.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to @dingo_d but he missed **wpautop()** in the code. Here is the updated code.

```
$more = ' <a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '" class="readMoreBtn">Read More</a>';

echo force_balance_tags( html_entity_decode( wp_trim_words( htmlentities( wpautop(get_the_content()) ), 100, $more ) ) );
```

Comment: If you'd remove wpautop() from it, it won't genearete extra <p> tags with gutenberg editor! But this works great!

Answer (score 4):

Aaaa I'm stupid. This will work (tested):

```
$more = ' <a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '" class="readMoreBtn">Read More</a>';
 echo force_balance_tags( html_entity_decode( wp_trim_words( htmlentities( get_the_content() ), 50, $more ) ) );
```

It took me a while to remember that `wp_trim_words()` strip all tags from the content it has, so your HTML wasn't displayed. So I did a little digging and found this gem:

Wordpress track ticket [#29533](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29533).

Hope this helps. Sorry for the confusion before :)

Comment: i have used the podcast player code in the content like [smart_track_player url="http://traffic.libsyn.com/abc/The_Seed_004__Hardwork_Pays_Off_With_Max_McGarity.mp3" title="Hard Work Pays Off With Max McGarity="abc" image="https://www.jakeszaraz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/TheSeedREALFinal.jpg" ] Please leave me an honest rating and review on ITunes by clicking here.   but when i have use your code html tags works fine but my podcast code does not work as player.

Comment: That's because this code outputs the html as is. May I recommend using [more tag](https://en.support.wordpress.com/more-tag/) `<-- more !-->` in your content, and just outputting the content. `wp_trim_words()` will strip html tags, and is not suitable for the excerpt. Alternatively I recommend you look at the [excellent post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt/141136#141136) by Pieter Goosen about the excerpt.

Comment: now works my code using  $more = ' <a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '" class="readMoreBtn">Read More</a>';
 $content= force_balance_tags( html_entity_decode( wp_trim_words( htmlentities( get_the_content() ), 50, $more ) ) ); echo do_shortcode($content);

Comment: Great! You can accept and/or upvote the answer if it helped :)